# Goal From/Off/On Long Pass

Tags: prepositions

Suppose the context is soccer (association football).

For these three sentences using "from", "off", and "on":

1. to score a goal ***from*** a long pass
2. to score a goal ***off*** a long pass
3. to score a goal ***on*** a long pass

do "from", "off", and "on" have different meanings?

Comment: I would say that #1 and #2 are interchangeable. You could also use _after_: to score a goal ***after*** a long pass.

Answer (score 1):

> to score a goal on a long pass

This would mean that a player was *trying* to do a long pass to a teammate, but the ball somehow ended up going in the net (*scoring a goal*) instead.

The first two have the same meaning, in that a player successfully passed the ball to a teammate and that teammate scored a goal.

Comment: The third may have the same meaning as the other two. In soccer I have found it only when the subject is the player who puts the ball in goal, ("Eduardo Vargas scored on a pass from Charles Arýnguiz"); but in hockey it is often said that a team "scores on a pass", and in US football the team, the quarterback and the receiver are all said to "score on a pass".